# aws sts get-caller-identity hangs if provider is Okta

Tags: okta, aws-sts

I have different profiles and currently have to deal with different identity providers. One of the provider is Okta. I am able to get my access keys using these different providers. My issue is when I need to ran the `sts get-caller-identity` because if it is an Okta profile, the command will just hang and I cannot even terminate the terminal with Cmd+Break. I have to close the window. I even check if there is a browser that redirects to an Okta url. I also checked if there is a push notification in the Okta authenticator app.

If it is other profiles that are not using Okta as the identity provider, it runs just fine.

`aws sts get-caller-identity --profile $non-okta-profile` - works just fine

`aws sts get-caller-identity --profile $non-existing-profile` - works just fine

`aws sts get-caller-identity --profile $non-okta-expired` - works just fine

`aws sts get-caller-identity --profile $okta-profile` - hangs

`aws sts get-caller-identity --profile $okta-profile-expired` - hangs